# Reciving Error 404 blog/page/2/

Tags: wp-query, pagination, 404-error

I can't seem to understand the issue here with my pagination? when visiting /blog/page/2  page goes to 404 page. Help me guys?

```
<div class="row">
                    <?php
                    // $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    if (get_query_var('paged')) {

                        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                    } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {

                        $paged = get_query_var('page');
                    } else {

                        $paged = 1;
                    }
                    $querys = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'blog',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'paged' => $paged
                    ));
                    if ($querys->have_posts()) {
                        while ($querys->have_posts()) {
                            $querys->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <a href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div class="news-modal-wrap radius5">
                                        <div class="new-img-wrap">
                                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) : ?>
                                                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>
                                                <img src="<?= $image[0] ?>" alt="">
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <div>
                                                <img src="<?= bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/images/logo2.png" class="logo2" alt="logo2">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="p-4">
                                            <?php
                                            $categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'blog_taxonomy');
                                            foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                                                <p class="d-inline value-btn p-1 radius5 text-uppercase"><?= $category->name; ?></p>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <h5 class="mt-4">
                                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                                            </h5>
                                            <p class="my-4">
                                                <?php $content = get_the_content();
                                                $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words($content, 25); ?>
                                                <?php echo $trimmed_content; ?>
                                            </p>
                                            <div class="new-date d-flex">
                                                <p><?= get_the_date(); ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php wp_reset_query();
                        }
                    } else { ?>
                        No Posts Found Of This <p class="d-inline value-btn p-1 radius5 text-uppercase"><?= $sector; ?> Category</p>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?= wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $querys)); ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function wphelp_custom_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
if( $query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_feed() && !is_admin() && is_category()) {
    $query->set( 'paged', str_replace( '/', '', get_query_var( 'page' ) ) );  }  }
add_action('pre_get_posts','wphelp_custom_pre_get_posts');
function wphelp_custom_request($query_string ) {
     if( isset( $query_string['page'] ) ) {
         if( ''!=$query_string['page'] ) {
             if( isset( $query_string['name'] ) ) { unset( $query_string['name'] ); } } } return $query_string; }
add_filter('request', 'wphelp_custom_request');
```

I have used this code and it helped me through for now.